AWS Cognito Pre-token-generation lambda is not called for client credentials flow
I created new Cognito User Pool and configured it to use Advanced Security Features. Then I created confidential client with client secret.
I created new Lambda and attached it as Pre-token generation handler with v2 event handling, which is supposed to handle access-token custom claims and scopes.
Then I initiated client credentials flow with confidential client and I successfully got new access-token.
However, it seems that Cognito does not invoke Pre-token generation lambda, so no custom claims and scopes are processed and added to the token.
I was unable to find any documentation about client credential flow not being supported. Is this not supported, is it documented or am I doing something wrong?
